# django-social-auth : custom response during pipeline execution

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I'm using [social-auth-app-django](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for Google authentication process. I created a custom pipeline and I want to return a `403 Forbidden` response under some certain conditions during the pipeline execution or somehow.

```
from social_core.exceptions import AuthFailed
def check_condition_pipeline(strategy, backend, details, response, *args, **kwargs):
    email = details['email']
    if email == 'check_email@domail.com':
        return {'is_new': False}
    else:
        raise AuthFailed(backend)
```

I tried `redirect()` method, but didn't get what I expected :( 

**UPDATE**

  I'm including what I've done after seeing some comments.

1.Changed custom pipeline function (Please look above).
2.Added custom Middleware class.

```
from social_django.middleware import SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware
from django.http import HttpResponse

class MySocialAuthExceptionMiddleware(SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if hasattr(exception, 'AuthFailed'):
            return HttpResponse("Not Autherised - Custom Response")
        else:
            raise exception
```

But, still I didn't get any `HttpResponse` :(

Comment: Have you tried raising an `AuthFailed` error there?

Comment: Then catching that (or a more specific custom exception such `AuthEmailNotAllowed`) in a social auth custom middleware exception and put your response there.

Comment: Tried, but it's raising an exception. My requirement is to return a `json_response` or `http_response`

Comment: You *want* the pipeline to raise an exception then catch that exception in custom social middleware which then returns your http/json response.

Comment: @JonClements I updated my question, please have a look

Comment: Django uses [PermissionDenied](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied) exception to signal a 403, this is catch by Django and calls the [permission_denied](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view) view, which in the end renders the template `403.html`, if you want a JSON response, then you need a middle to customize this response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `MySocialAuthExceptionMiddleware` class as below ;

```
from social_core.exceptions import AuthFailed


class MySocialAuthExceptionMiddleware(SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, AuthFailed):
            return HttpResponse("Not Autherised - Custom Response", status=403))
```